# Max-priority Queue in the Java's standard Collections. Is there one?

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue

I need a `Max-Priority Queue` data structure.

Looking in Java's [Priority Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) I noticed that it is a `Min-Priority Queue`.

From javadoc:

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the
>   specified ordering

I saw that there is the option to provide a custom `Comparator` and looking at some posts some suggest to use one and do the reverse comparison to achieve the result of a `Max Priority Queue`.
This seems to me though a "ugly-hack" and perhaps not intuitive.

Is this the only way to have a `Max-Priority Queue` from the Java's standard collection?
Is there a more appropriate object I am missing? (E.g. a while back I didn't realize that `Stack` was replaced by a `Deque`...my bad)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, yes, it's the best way to have what you want. I really don't see how it's an ugly hack. There is no point of providing two different classes if just one is sufficient. If we followed your reasoning, we would have a MinTreeSet and a MaxTreeSet, a MinTreeMap and a MaxTreeMap, etc., all doining exactly the same thing. It's a classical use of the strategy pattern.

Just use [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29) to get a comparator that compares in the reverse order of the natural ordering.

Comment: (+1) for `Collections.reverseOrder()`

Comment: I saw it as an ugly hack from the perspective that the javadoc explicitely mention it as a priority queue.They don't say, the ordering can be reversed and pass the appropriate comparator. But your comment for strategy makes sense so +1.It is just that I don't think this is clear from the javadoc

Comment: @user384706: Priority can be anything. A descending priority is just as valid as an ascending one. Don't think of it as a reverse min-priority, think of it a max-priority, where the comparator specifies this directly.

Comment: Well, the second sentence of the javadoc says: *The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time*. I don't think it could be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a Min-Heap. You are misinterpreting this part:

> The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the
>   specified ordering.

The emphasis is on **specified ordering**. That can be anything, including a descending comparison. Providing your own comparator is how it's supposed to be used and it's definitely not an "ugly hack".

Right at the beginning:

> This queue orders elements according to an order specified at
>   construction time, which is specified either according to their
>   natural order (see Comparable), or according to a Comparator,
>   depending on which constructor is used.

This clearly states that providing your own comparator is expected behavior.

Comment: Ok, specified ordering but the least element.

Comment: @user384706: Least here is not least in a numerical sense where out of { 3, 1, 2 }, 1 is the least. It is least in the sense that it has the "least priority" according to the specified comparison.

Comment: @ Tudor:I don't see how this is different from my interpretation.I mean it is the least

Comment: Yes, the least priority. If you provide a descending comparator, then the maximum value has the least priority, even though numerically it is the largest value.

Comment: This is global to the collections API : wherever Comparators are applicable, you have to get used to the concept of "least according to" or "least with respect to".  It has a specific, well-defined, useful meaning.